# append the data at each section while didselect

Tags: ios

This is my code:-

```
 let selectedIndexPathAtCurrentSection = questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.filter({ $0.section == indexPath.section})

            print(selectedIndexPathAtCurrentSection)

                for indexPath in selectedIndexPathAtCurrentSection {
                    print(indexPath)

                    tableview.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
                    if let indexOf = questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.index(of: indexPath) {
                        questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.remove(at: indexOf)
                    }
                }
                questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths.append(indexPath)

                print(questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths)
                print(indexPath)
```

So according to this

when didselect the row. output shows as:-

```
[[0,0]]
```

### this is for 1st section .Suppose i select 2nd index then the output as below

```
[[0,1]]
```

This output will display at questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths

when i select 2nd section option then output of questionViewModel.selectedIndexPaths will display as below.

```
[[1,0]]
```

But while selectng each section i need to append as below.

```
[[0,1],[1,0]]
```

How to implement ?

Comment: you can take array and append element in array..

Comment: Using an array to store selected index paths is a Bad Idea™, as your indices will change as you add and remove elements.  Use a `Set<IndexPath>` instead.

Comment: @sagar can u show how to implement here?

Comment: @SagarBhut how to append the data at each section?

Comment: @Paulw11 can u show how to implement?